# kpasswd - Incorrect net address changing password

Tags: kerberos

I setup a server on AWS with krb5-kdc.

```
$ dpkg -l  | grep krb5
ii  krb5-admin-server                1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.3                       amd64        MIT Kerberos master server (kadmind)
ii  krb5-kdc                         1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.3                       amd64        MIT Kerberos key server (KDC)
ii  krb5-user                        1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.3                       amd64        Basic programs to authenticate using MIT Kerberos
```

I can `kadmin.local`, `kinit`. But `kpasswd` failed

```
kpasswd: Incorrect net address changing password
```

How can I fix this?

P.S. after little google I found [mail from Russ Allbery](https://marc.info/?l=kerberos&m=143346661621724&w=2)
But I am not using Microsoft AD. and clueless now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three difference network area besides one with KDC.

So when I tried to `kpasswd` on those three area. 
two area succeeded and one raises the error.

So I worked around by using other IP address for KDC in that area. (KDC had two IP addresses)